# Pass variable into constructor while creating the variable

Tags: typescript, class, variables, constructor

I have the following problem:

I have customized my Discord Client to have more properties (e.g., player or db).
For creating the player, I have to pass the client into the Player constructor.

My Code:

```
const client = new Client({
  clientConfig: {
    intents: [
      Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
      Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
      Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
      Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
    ],
  },
  dbConfig: {
    host: process.env['DB_HOST'],
    database: process.env['DB_NAME'],
    password: process.env['DB_PASSWORD'],
    user: process.env['DB_USER'],
    connectionLimit: 5,
    multipleStatements: true,
  },
  playerOptions: {
    searchSongs: 5000,
    searchCooldown: 10,
    leaveOnEmpty: false,
    leaveOnFinish: false,
    leaveOnStop: false,
    plugins: [
      new SpotifyPlugin({
        api: {
          clientId: process.env['SPOTIFY_CLIENTID'],
          clientSecret: process.env['SPOTIFY_CLIENTSECRET'],
        },
      }),
      new SoundCloudPlugin(),
    ],
  },
  // The client I'm defining. So I get an error that the variable doesn't exists
  client: client,
});
```

EDIT:

In the extended Class `this` is the client that is being constucted. So I could just use `this` instead of passing in the client in the main File

Comment: It's not about *variables*. You can't pass an object that isn't created yet to the function you're calling to create it.  The object initializer is evaluated **before** `Client` is called (because otherwise, there'd be no object to pass to it). I haven't used this API, but I'm certain it doesn't make sense to specify the client to itself. If the `Client` constructor needs that information, it will already have it (as `this`).

Comment: (And separately, `client` doesn't have a value until `new Client` has finished its work and returned -- a similar chicken-and-egg problem.)

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround by lazy init, e.g. use a function,

```
class Client {
  type: number;
  client: ()=> Client;
  constructor(arg: any) {
    this.type = arg.type;
    this.client = arg.client;
  }
}


const client  = new Client({
  type: 1,
  client: ()=> client,
})


console.log(client.client()) // { type: 1}
```